# Tag Synonym: Destiny Rise of Iron -> Destiny

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are currently two questions tagged to [destiny-rise-of-iron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny-rise-of-iron). When other Destiny DLC were released, the tags [destiny-taken-king](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny-taken-king) and [destiny-house-of-wolves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny-house-of-wolves) were created, but were later updated to be synonyms for [destiny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny)

The tag for Rise of Iron should also be updated to be a synonym for Destiny to match the other DLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that the other two expansions were turned into synonyms of the base game, I agree that [destiny-rise-of-iron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny-rise-of-iron) should become a synonym of [destiny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny), as well.